# on a Chromebook converted to Linux running KDE, how to fully move Ctrl to left-of-A?

Tags: linux, kde, keyboard

I'm running a Chromebook converted to Linux with EndeavourOS and KDE.  I'm having trouble repurposing the key-to-the-left-of-A (i.e., "Search") as the Control key completely.

The closest that I have gotten (and I've tried many variations) is in the Keyboard settings:

- Keyboard model: "Google Chromebook"
- Advanced / Ctrl Position: Check "Swap Left Win with Left Ctl"
- Advanced / Compatibility Options: "Both Shifts together enable Caps Lock"

In a terminal, Ctrl-C works as expected, but in tmux, Ctrl-A behaves improperly and just shows "^X@s^A".

If I run `xev`, then the key press events for Ctrl-C and Ctrl-A look the same except for the A and C characters.

Anybody know what is going on? Or, even better, how to make Ctrl-A work for tmux when Ctrl is left-of-A?

Comment: Please do inform whether you are running your KDE-Plasma having X11 or Wayland backend.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on the KDE settings. Instead I'm using [input-remapper](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper).  It works for both X11 and Wayland and w/o the trial-and-error (and failure) of using the KDE settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xev to check the keycode for your search key, and which key it is mapped to.

First, create file `.Xmodmap` at your `$HOME` directory with content below

```
clear control
clear mod4
keycode 133 = KeyCode
add control  = Control_L Control_R KeyCode
add mod4 = KeyCode Super_R
```

replace `KeyCode` with the one you find out with xev

Next, need to make sure `xmodmap` load `~/.Xmodmap` file when you start you linux

add this line to your .profile

```
if [ -s ~/.Xmodmap ]; then
    xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
fi
```

[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279822/chromebook-map-search-key-to-ctrl-ubuntu)

Comment: according to the arch wiki, no https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xmodmap#Reassigning_modifiers_to_keys_on_your_keyboard @MC68020

Comment: Arghh ! My bad. I must have been mislead somewhere ! I delete my comment at once & apologize. (BTW, restricted to KDE, if OP using wayland backend, I'd be surprise it works anyway) yet another comment of mine to be deleted ?… wait&see… ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it does not seem to work my Chromebook conversion using MrChromebox firmware. I'll ask the MrChromebox forums ... it is probably a firmware quirk. -- OP

Answer (score 0):

Using KDE, you should be able to achieve that under :

System-Settings > Input Devices > Keyboard > Advanced

Mark the Configure keyboard options checkbox,

Then find the ***Ctrl position*** item and develop,

Then check the ***To the left of "A"*** choice.

(works on my kde-plasma-5.25.5)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and that works for my Windows laptop converted to Linux (as do several other choices), but not for my Chromebook conversion using MrChromebox. I'll ask the MrChromebox forums ... it is probably a firmware quirk. -- OP

Comment: @GammaZoid : I don't (yet) think it being a firmware issue. Would you be using Wayland as backend ?